# Fatal error: Call to a member function getKeyName()

Tags: joomla, member

I am new in joomla . i have created a joomla component and when  i click on new button in admin then i am getting such error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getKeyName() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla1\libraries\joomla\application\component\modeladmin.php on line 801

Please help

Comment: Provide the code from your model!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is cause by your JTable class. Make sure you have correct filename and class name in **administrator/components/com_YOUREXTENSION/tables/**
You can find example in any core Joomla extension.

Comment: Helped me after 7 years. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getTable($type = 'Category', $prefix = 'CatalogTable', $config = array())

{
    return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
}
```

Check your $prefix param!I also just this faulty. My component is: com_catalog, and the $prefix = 'CatalogTable'