# Joomla component multiple views

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla

I've read up and done the tutorials for Joomla 3. Here is my problem:
My requirement is more complex than the HelloWorld one.  I have multiple tables, on the admin side, to maintain (entries - add, update and delete).  Thus it means multiple controllers, views and models (one for each database table)

To explain:
Lets say I have 2 tables in the database; **shop** and **area**. The default view is for **shop**.  I've created MVCs called *shop* and *shops* - working.  Then I created MVCs called *area* and *areas*.  The *areas* one works to show a list of the areas in the DB.

The *area* view works (display the right form, but no data) but there is something wrong with the model; when I look at **MyCompViewArea** Object's item member, item, it still have the array for *shop*.

I'm stuck, can you point me to a comprehensive tutorial that covers this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, silly me!

One gets blind to one's code.  I've kept on hunting for the problem and because of another question ask ([Fatal error: Call to a member function getKeyName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156707/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getkeyname)) I took a closer look at my table class and found that the class name was wrong.  It was **MyCompTableMyComp** instead of **MyCompTableArea**